# How to count the number of date-specific newly data entered on an increasing range from row x?

Tags: range, google-sheets-formula, countif

I need formulas that do these things for me automatically

1. Count and display the number of new pieces of data added to the spreadsheet =TODAY()
2. On a separate sheet, list the number of new pieces of data added to the main sheet each day
3. Count the average number of pieces of content added to the spreadsheet in a given month

The challenge for me here is that every new data is being inserted on the top row of the spreadsheet just below the header so the start of the range changes every time. Is there a way to permanently include in the range all the newly inserted rows below the header? Here's the [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x2sE3KJrYu5A8poUac3vgRJpP5Ro1bI5BNIFpxhDkGY/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in cell H1:

```
={COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D"), TODAY());ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(
 INDIRECT("B4:B"), "content", MONTH(
 INDIRECT("D4:D")), MONTH(TODAY()))/COUNTIFS(MONTH(
 INDIRECT("D4:D")), MONTH(TODAY())))}
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense!! Thank you! Really appreciate your help @player0

Can you help me in filling the second tab named DRAFT: Average? I've used countif too but my criterion is not working when I try to compare it against the dates on the columns. I tried match and sum and it still looks like I'm missing a big part.

Comment: try in Q3: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D4:D"), Q1)`

Comment: Terrific! Thanks @player0